# Android: Reload method in main activity when method in second activity executes successfully and closes

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to build an app that enables you to change your profile picture. When the app opens for the first time, it contains a `Networkimageview` for the current profile pic and a button to change the picture. When the button is pressed a new `Activity` is started that enables one to choose an image from the gallery and upload to a server.

When the upload is done, the new `Activity` is closed and the app returns to the `MainActivity`. How can I make the `MainActivity` to reload the image just uploaded to the server when the image uploads successfully from the new activity and closes? This is my code

Here's the `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    NetworkImageView mNetworkImageView;
    private Button buttonChoose;
    static final int PROFILE_PICTURE_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);

        mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.networkImageView);

        loadImage();
    }

    private String url = "http://10.0.2.2/images/0.jpg";

    private void loadImage() {
        mImageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this).getImageLoader();
        mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(url, mImageLoader);
    }

    public void newActivity(View view) {
        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivityForResult(profileIntent, PROFILE_PICTURE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PROFILE_PICTURE_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                loadImage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second activity `Activity2.java`

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private String UPLOAD_URL ="http://10.0.2.2/uploadd.php";
    private String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
    private Button buttonUpload;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

        imageView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }

    public void uploadImage() {
        //Showing the progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Uploading...", "Please wait...", false, false);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();

                        setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        //Dismissing the progress dialog
                        loading.dismiss();
                        //Showing toast
                        Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                //Converting Bitmap to String
                String image = getStringImage(bitmap);
                //Creating parameters
                Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
                //Adding parameters
                params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);

                //returning parameters
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Creating a Request Queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == buttonUpload){
            uploadImage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your basic setup with startActivityForResult and onActivityResult is right.  Are you sure the URL is correct after the upload?  Did you verify via browser?

Comment: What does `loadImage()` do?

Comment: Make your server return the URL of the new image as a response. Once you get this in your `SecondActivity`, pass it to the `MainActivity` via `intent.putExtra` method. Now in your `MainActivity`'s `onActivityResult` you can fetch this URL. Update your `url` variable with this new URL and then call the `loadImage` method.

Comment: The URL is correct. The profile picture changes when i restart the app. @GabeSechan

Comment: loadImage() gets the image from the server @DavidWasser

Comment: Override the `onResume` method and call `loadImage` method in it.

Comment: @PfilMintz I assume you've used breakpoints to double check that onActivityResult and loadImage are being called?

Comment: @Gabe Sechan What if they are not being called? How can i make sure they are called?

Comment: @PfilMintz If they are being called, then everything is working right.  If they aren't, that's your problem and we need to figure it out.  If they are, your problem is probably in the volley library not updating the image view.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan Sorry to ask too many questions but i can tell if they are being called or not from setting the breakpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're finishing the `Activity2` on a successful image upload, you need to put some extras in the intent which is passed to the launcher activity which is `MainActivity`.

So the `onResponse` segment of your `uploadImage()` function should look like the following. Declare the `filePath` variable as `public` so that you can use it here too.

```
// Declare filePath as public 
Uri filePath;

@Override
public void onResponse(String s) {
    loading.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("UPDATED_PIC", filePath.toString());

    setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Now from your `MainActivity` handle the `retuneIntent` to get the `filePath` and load the image from there. So the `onActivityResult` may look like -

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PROFILE_PICTURE_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if(data != null) {
              Uri filePath = Uri.parse(extras.getString("UPDATED_PIC"));
              try {
                  //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                  Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                  // Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                  mNetworkImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please I am getting a java.lang.NullPointerException on "returnIntent.putExtra("UPDATED_PIC", filePath.toString())"@Reaz Murshed

Comment: Then you've an invalid `filePath`. As I've said earlier, you need to declare the `filePath` as global and use it later while passing it in `returnIntent`.